# How to dockerize my flask web app with mysql database?Cannot connect mysql and cannot found render templete

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask

I am new to docker and trying to deploy this web app but cannot find solution.
I’m running windows 10 and Docker Desktop. My docker-version is 19.03.5 and docker-compose version 1.25.4, build unknown.

My directory structure is:

```
  -docker-compose.yml
  -app
     -static
          js/
            script.js
          css/
              style.css
     -templates
            -index.html
     -app.py
     -dockerfile
     -requirements.txt
  -db
    -init.sql
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
app:
  build: ./app
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"

db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "32000:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  volumes:
    - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
EXPOSE 5000
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN ls /app
COPY static /app/static
COPY templates /app/templates
COPY app.py /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask
mysql-connector
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import mysql.connector
import os

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/templates', static_folder='/static')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user = 'root',
        password = 'root',
        host= 'db',
        port = '3306',
        database = 'test'
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name from place")
    names = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', names = names)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**My docker command is –**

```
docker-compose up
```

Then trying to access  http://0.0.0.0:5000/ but get mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' and  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:

Comment: Isn't the `ports` option host_port:container_port so in `app.py` use `port =  '32000'` instead of `port = '3306',`

Comment: @Orion I also tried it but did not work. It show the same error.Please help

Comment: `app.py` is used within the container so I would avoid using `host='0.0.0.0` as this can refer to the local bridge whiten the container. what happens when you run `wget 0.0.0.0:3306` and `wget 0.0.0.0:32000` from the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Your flask folder paths are wrong, it should be either an absolute path like `/app/templates` and `/app/static` or a relative one like `templates` abnd `static`.

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306'

If your init.sql script is correct then there is nothing wrong with your database, you just have let it initialize properly (wait for the `mysqld: ready for connections` message) before sending your first request.

Comment: is path wrong in app.py folder and where should I write `mysqld: ready for connection`

Comment: @Ferdousi, just check the mysql logs. I tested your code and it works perfectly, the only thing was that MySQL took like 40 seconds to initialize the database (the first time) and every request before it was ready gave me your error. Maybe you have an error in your init.sql and the database never went up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I follow it. MySQL takes 40 seconds so I need to docker-compose build then wait and docker-compose up. it finally works